# soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser") print(soup.title)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

When I tried to run this code it give me a
**NameError**: name 'soup' is not defined

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre].

Comment: What is "this code"? Please edit your question to contain all relevant information

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your referencing `soup` by printing `soup.title` before it's instantiated. Try this:

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title)
```